# Convert a program that uses includes to one using templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, include

I have created an example to show the language features I am using, the real case is not as simple. The include file is included twice, once for each class. Even though the text is the same, the underlying types are different. In the real case some variables have more initialization than others depending on the class.

Working program

ex1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class one {
public:
   one(int a1,int b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   int a,b;
#include "ex1.h"
};

class two {
public:
   two(double a1,double b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   double a,b;
#include "ex1.h"
};

int main()
{
   one c1(1,2);
   two c2(3.4,5.7);
   c1.f();
   c2.f();
   return 0;
}
```

ex1.h

```
void f()
{
    std::cout << ( a + b ) << std::endl;
}
```

I was hoping to change this to a program that uses templates as follows, but I get a compile error.

ex2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

class one {
public:
   one(int a1,int b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   int a,b;
   void f();
};

class two {
public:
   two(double a1,double b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   double a,b;
   void f();
};

template<typename X>
void X::f()
{  
    std::cout << ( a + b ) << std::endl;
}  

int main()
{
   one c1(1,2);
   two c2(3.4,5.7);
   c1.f();
   c2.f();
   return 0;
}
```

The error message is error: invalid use of template type parameter 'X'

Comment: `f` is a member function so you need to have a templated class in order to get what you want here. Specifically I don't know of a way you can have a member function be shared between 2 classes like this. Perhaps if it were made as free function you get the result you want.

Comment: Is `X` a class template of which `f` is a member of?

Comment: That is not the way to use templates. This tutorial gives a good introduction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part

Comment: You have fundamental misconceptions about how to use templates. Your question seems to be unanswerable.

Comment: This looks like a job for CRTP, but your example falls too far short of what we must infer you actually want to do for that to be demonstrated.  But read about CRTP anyway.  It is a great way to inject common features into dissimilar classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to the rescue:

```
template<class D>
struct f_support {
  void f() {
    // does not block all errors, but catches some:
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< f_support, D >::value, "CRTP failure" );
    auto* dis = static_cast<D*>(this);
    std::cout << ( dis->a + dis->b ) << std::endl;
  }
};
```

then:

```
class one: public f_support<one> {
```

...

```
class two: public f_support<two> {
```

...

You could move the implementation of `f_support<D>` into a .cpp file, but that is a hassle.

Comment: I don't totally understand it, but it works. It allows for classes to have different implementations other than the functions I care about.

Comment: @RobertJacobs CRTP lets you inject code into derived classes, and know the full type of the derived classes at the point of implementation.  It is a pattern that curiously reoccurs in a lot of code.  Note that at the point of inheritance, if you don't pass in the right `D`erived class, bad things happen.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the correct way to do what you want is to use a template to handle the different types present in the class:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename X>
class foo {
public:
   foo(X a1, X b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   X a,b;
   void f();
};

template<typename X>
void foo<X>::f()
{  
    std::cout << ( a + b ) << std::endl;
}  

int main()
{
   foo<int> c1(1,2);
   foo<double> c2(3.4,5.7);
   c1.f();
   c2.f();
   return 0;
}
```

Generally speaking you don't want to `#include` code directly into your class to remove code duplication, c++ gives you some better options.
You can see this run here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34d146d7feac8abd

Comment: In the real world, class two has variables that class one does not. Class two has extra initialization in the constructor that class one does not.

Comment: In that case you could make a base class that contains all the common functionality that is shared and make the `one` and `two` classes derived from that base class. The derived classes can then handle the differences.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank @Yakk and @shuttle87 for their answers. I took the simplicity of shuttle87's answer and the flexibility of Yakk's answer to come up with this one. Without your help, I would still be using include files. <s>The problem with my solution below is that it requires all classes to have the same number of arguments in their constructor.</s>

```
#include <iostream>

class one {
public:
   one(int a1,int b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   int a,b;
   void g() { std::cout << "one\t"; }
};

class two {
public:
   two(double a1,double b1) : a(a1), b(b1) {}
   double a,b;
   void g() { std::cout << "two\t"; }
};

template<class X, typename Y>
class three : public X {
public:
    three(Y a, Y b) : X(a,b) {}    
    void f()
    {
        X::g();
        std::cout << ( X::a + X::b ) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   three<one,int> c1(1,2);
   three<two,double> c2(3.4,5.7);
   c1.f();
   c2.f();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The problem with my solution below is that it requires all classes to have the same number of arguments in their constructor." I'm assuming you don't mean something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73b228687a37ab25 ? There are some other ways of getting this type of thing done.