# Copying data between mixin types

Tags: c++, mixins

I have some different types of data that I want to be able to add to an object (here called "A" and "B"). If I add them in the same order for two different objects, copying one to the other works fine (e.g. `A<B<Point> > abPoint1; A<B<Point> > abPoint2 = abPoint1;`). However, if I add them in different orders (e.g. `A<B<Point> > abPoint; B<A<Point> > baPoint = abPoint; // compiler error`) because the type signature is not the same. Is there any way to do this without handling an exponential number of mixin combinations explicitly?

Here is a MWE for testing:

```
// Standard point representation
struct Point
{
    double x,y,z;
};

// A mixin to add an 'A' value to a point
template<class Base>
class A : public Base
{
public:

    double a;
};

// A mixin to add an 'B' value to a point
template<class Base>
class B : public Base
{
public:

    double b;
};

int main()
{
  A<Point> aPoint;

  B<Point> bPoint;

  // A<Point> a2Point = bPoint; // obviously we can't do this

  A<B<Point> > abPoint;
  B<A<Point> > baPoint;

  abPoint = baPoint; // Something like this seems like it should be possible

  return 0;
}
```

And even better, is there a way to only copy "available" pieces of the data? That is:

```
A<B<C<D<Point>>>> abcdPoint; 
A<C<Point>> acPoint; 
abcdPoint = acPoint;
```

would only copy the members from A and C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789582/convert-a-program-that-uses-includes-to-one-using-templates. The answer to this question that references CRTP may help you. It will allow you to recast 'this' and other arguments to test if they have the data you need, and write an operator = to perform the operation.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I follow that. So here I would need to template Point? Then for which class would I write an operator=? Would each one just copy their own data (are they automatically called "recursively"?)?

Comment: hmm.. so lets say you had a class C : public Base with a member variable double a;  and then you did- A<Point> aPoint; C<Point> cPoint;  cPoint = aPoint  <-- (in this case you'd want to copy x,y,z and a?  because they both have a member named 'a' of type double)

Comment: @KorreyD Not quite - it's actually stronger than that. If I have an A<C<Point>> acPoint and an A<Point> aPoint, I want acPoint = aPoint to copy everything from the A class, because that's the only mixin they have in common. Likewise, acPoint = point would just copy the members of Point. It needs to scale though, so like A<B<C<D<Point>>>> abcdPoint; A<C<Point>> acPoint; abcdPoint = acPoint would only copy the members from A and C. See what I mean? I've added this description to the question as this is really what I'm going for.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able show what I think the answer to be without really testing to see if it works, I will call this an answer.

```
template<class BASE>
class A {
public:
  A<BASE> operator=(const &A<BASE> right) {
    // does not block all errors, but catches some:
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< A, BASE >::value, "CRTP failure" );
    auto* dis = static_cast<BASE*>(this);
    BASE::operator=(right);
    dis->a = right.a;
    return this;
  }
  double a;
};

template<class BASE>
class B {
public:
  B<BASE> operator=(const &B<BASE> right) {
    // does not block all errors, but catches some:
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< B, BASE >::value, "CRTP failure" );
    auto* dis = static_cast<BASE*>(this);
    dis->b = right.b;
    BASE::operator=(right);
    return this;
  }
  double b;
};


class aPoint: public A<aPoint>, Point {};

class bPoint: public B<bPoint>, Point {};

class abPoint: public B < A<abPoint> > {};

class baPoint: public A < B<baPoint> > {};
```

Comment: Before I try a more complex example, shouldn't this work? https://gist.github.com/daviddoria/4ea5d826684993b1e4ef I am getting "Conversion from Point to non-scalar type A<Point> requested" - isn't that what the templated assignment operator supposed to handle?

Comment: You need to copy a or b in your operator=. Since it won't compile unless a (or b) exists in the right hand side, it may work.

Comment: In that gist I am intentionally NOT copying 'a' in operator= so that it would just copy in the data from Point. But it seems like the template operator= is not getting used, but rather the default operator=?

Comment: this code -> A<Point> aPoint = point;  calls a copy constructor (since aPoint is being declared and assigned at the same time). what you have overridden in your code there is the copy assignment operator. so if you want it to hit that piece of code you want to do: A<Point> aPoint; aPoint=point;

Comment: @KorreyD Ah, of course, thanks. Back to the harder case... haha

Comment: @RobertJacobs So what happens if I try to copy a `A<B<Point> >` into a `A<Point>` (I would want x,y,z, and a to be copied, and b to be forgotten)? Even if the static_cast fails, there would be a compiler error trying to access `this->b`, you see what I mean? The goal is to copy all of the data that exists both in the source and the target.

Answer (score 0):

I fleshed out your example the best I could. Copying a abPoint into a baPoint works.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
public:
    double x,y,z;
};

// A mixin to add an 'A' value to a point
template<class Base>
class A : public Base
{
public:
    A& operator=( const Point& rhs )
    {
        Point::operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T_RHS>
    A& operator=( const T_RHS& rhs )
    {
        Base::operator=(rhs);
        a = rhs.a;
        return *this;
    }

    double a;
};

// A mixin to add an 'B' value to a point
template<class Base>
class B : public Base
{
public:
    B& operator=( const Point& rhs )
    {
        Point::operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T_RHS>
    B& operator=( const T_RHS& rhs )
    {
        Base::operator=(rhs);
        b = rhs.b;
        return *this;
    }

    double b;
};

int main()
{
  Point point;

  A<Point> aPoint;
  aPoint = point;

  B<Point> bPoint;
  bPoint = point;

  B< A<Point> > baPoint;
  A< B<Point> > abPoint;
  abPoint = baPoint;

  // Fails
  //aPoint = bPoint;
  //bPoint = aPoint;

  // This works
  aPoint.Point::operator=(bPoint);
  bPoint.Point::operator=(aPoint);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: weird, any idea why the normal assignment operator fails? So this fixes the ordering problem (AB vs BA), but it looks like it won't work if there is a different subset of mixins (e.g. AC vs AB) - that is AC will try to copy C from whatever is passed in (AB) which will fail, right?

Comment: The type of the rhs is wrong. My guess is if the rhs was cast to a point, the normal = would work.